# redux toolkit createAsuncThunk thunkApi return types

Tags: redux-toolkit

I'm trying to delete a todo while using thunkApi.fulfillwithValue and thunkApi.rejectWithValue but I cant seem to get the types right.

```
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
interface DeleteTodoError {
  message: string;
}
interface DeleteTodoSuccess {
  message: string;
}
export const deleteTodos = createAsyncThunk<DeleteTodoError | DeleteTodoSuccess, number>(
  'todos/delete',
  async (todoId: number, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${process.env.baseUrl}/todos/${todoId}`, {
        method: 'delete',
      });
      if (response.status === 200) {
        return thunkApi.fulfillWithValue({
          message: 'todo deleted successfully',
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue({
        message: 'failed to delete todo',
      });
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rejected` type is defined in the third generic argument.

[You can find the docs on that here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk)

```
export const deleteTodos = createAsyncThunk<
DeleteTodoSuccess, 
number, 
{
  rejectValue: DeleteTodoError 
}
>(
```